# calls write with a command built from untrusted data

Tags: java, findbugs, fortify

code:

```
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
outputStream.flush();
```

Fortify error message: medium level

The method run() in SomeFile.java calls write() with a command built from untrusted data. This call can cause the program to execute malicious commands on behalf of an attacker.

How do I fix it?

Java version: 1.8

Code is similar to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/outputstream_write_byte_len.htm)

Comment: The call doesn't make any sense. What is it trying to achieve? i.e. if the length is not 4096 it will either be wasting memory or will cause an Exception.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it is old code written long back, I need fix only outputStream.write, there is no issues with what parameter is passed.

Comment: Where is the outputstream going to? I'm not sure how an outputstream could be exploited, unless it's writing code which will be compiled or executed.

Comment: it is going to write to JVM memory.

Comment: Check that the data is valid and as expected before writing it

Comment: All this does is write `length` of `0` byte.  The warning is spurious because the line of code makes no sense, which is confusing the checker.  If you fix the code to do something useful, or more logical, I expect the warning will go away.

Comment: what fix I need to here? do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Fortify SCA lists the function outputStream.write() has a sink API. Meaning that it would be dangerous if untrusted and unvalidated data were to reach that function's input parameters. I am not sure where you're getting the source buffer but here Fortify consider that the buffer variable (or length variable ) may be tainted with unvalidated data. There are two ways to remove the issue:

1. You can mark it as false positive in your FPR file, and merge it with all new scans so your audit persists across your next reviews.
2. You can write a cleanse rules where you teach Fortify to recognize your cleanse API. For instance, you may have the code:

   `buffer = getUntrustedDataFromWeb(Request);`

`Validator.validate(buffer); //white list the accepted characters (e.g. A-Z,a-z,0-9)`

`length = buffer.size();`

`outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);`

`outputStream.flush();`

A Cleanse custom rules would look like:

```
    <DataflowCleanseRule formatVersion="3.2" language="java">
    <MetaInfo>
        <Group name="package">Java Core Web</Group>
    </MetaInfo>
    <RuleID>702AB36D-4473-4CD5-B656-5D1040B59F07</RuleID>
    <Notes><![CDATA[
Validate the data]]></Notes>
    <FunctionIdentifier>
        <NamespaceName>
            <Value>com.web.util</Value>
        </NamespaceName>
        <ClassName>
            <Value>Validator</Value>
        </ClassName>
        <FunctionName>
            <Value>validate</Value>
        </FunctionName>
        <Parameters/>
        <ApplyTo implements="true" overrides="true" extends="true"/>
    </FunctionIdentifier>
    <OutArguments>this</OutArguments>
</DataflowCleanseRule>
```

You would have to add the above custom rule next time you run Fortify (see sourceanalyzer -h for syntax).